# Are there any major difference between Season 1 and 2 of Dragon Ball Super and the Dragonball Z movies they are named from?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

Season 1 of Dragonball Z Super is *Battle of Gods* and Season 2 is *Resurrection F*, the same names as 2 Dragonball Z Movies.. now if we assume 20 minutes air time each episode for both series (- OP and EDs and possible ad breaks) this means

- *Battle of Gods*

  - Series = `14 x 20 = 280` Minutes footage
  - Movie = [85-105 Minutes footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Battle_of_Gods) (theatrical-Fuji TV)
- *Resurrection F*

  - Series = `13 x 20 = 260` Minutes footage
  - Movie = [94 Minutes footage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Resurrection_%27F%27)

this shows that both season have more footage than their original movies. Are there any major difference between Season 1 and 2 of Dragon Ball Super and the Dragonball Z movies they are named from that would warrant someone who has been the 2 movies to watch the first 2 seasons.

Comment: There are some details that might be relevant in later developments of the story concepts or not, but how to tell you without spoiling you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm talking about what I remember but generally if you watched the movies, skip the first two seasons because they are just a time waster and for the most part really boring.

In the first movie when Goku encountered Beerus he immediately switched to SSJ3 to fight him, where in the anime he fought in the SS1 and SS2 forms first. Also after the battle, in the movie Beerus mentioned that he was using 70% of his strength while in the anime he simply said he was not using all of his power. I'm sure there are some more details I have missed (oh yeah maybe another important one: in the movie they were fighting at the Capsule Corp headquarter while in the series the battle was on a cruise ship.

The second movie: most notable changes in the anime are that Ginyu swapped bodies with Tagoma and that Piccolo had died. Also there is a difference in how the dragon wishes were used but I don't remember how it went right.

If you plan to watch the series, as I said before you can skip the first 2 seasons, nothing major was changed and it is a real slog. Almost an entire episode was dedicated to Goku's transformation to a God. They literally stand in the circle for 10 minutes while he was transforming.

Answer (score 0):

There are some details that might be relevant in later developments of the story concepts or not. For example

> In the movie , when wounded by Sorbet's laser , Goku is in Super Saiyan Blue, in the series he's in base form. This might be relevant or not to a story concept, to the idea of if a Super Saiyan Blue can lower his ki to base level or not. (It would seem in the series they fixed the idea that a Super Saiyan Blue could be hurt by a simple laser, but it's not clear.
> Another more relevant is in the series is shown Goku Super Saiyan God (red) have regeneration habilities, something that isnt show in the movie

Those are minor details that might be more important or not in the future, depending how the story concepts evolve

About differences that last long, there are several ones, for example

> Tagoma kills Shisami in the series. In the series Tagoma is shown to be extremely powerful, to the point of being able to fight Roshi, Krilin, Piccolo and Gohan in base form at the same time. Captain Ginyu appears in the series (it doesnt appear in the movie) and steals Tagoma body. Later Ginyu is killed by Vegeta . 
> Gotenks has some intervention in the series fight, something that doesnt happen in the movie. Those are some of the differences.

In conclusion, worth watching the series in my opinion to see those differences I mentioned in the spoilers section of the post

Comment: BTW, the regeneration habilities shown in the series which dont exist in the movie, might make that form perfect to use it for a higher level of kaioken, even better than base form. If they had the intention or realize about that, we dont know, but Toyotaro in the manga uses to explore ideas like that, if you read the last chapter of the manga you'll know what I mean. And let's not forget Toyotaro who is running the manga is a former fan with a former Dragon Ball fan work, so it wont be a surprise if the fandom has a stronger influence over his ideas than it has over Toei or Toriyama